# Sort each subarray of a multidimensional array by a column value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have the following array and I want to sort the subarrays by `value`.

```
[
    'bwin' => [
        ['bookie' => 'bwin', 'id_bookie' => 178537, 'value' => 6.00, 'bet' => 1],
        ['bookie' => 'bwin', 'id_bookie' => 178537, 'value' => 1.45, 'bet' => 2],
        ['bookie' => 'bwin', 'id_bookie' => 178537, 'value' => 4.50, 'bet' => 'x']
    ],
    'NordicBet' => [
        ['bookie' => 'NordicBet', 'id_bookie' => 201581, 'value' => 5.75, 'bet' => 1],
        ['bookie' => 'NordicBet', 'id_bookie' => 201581, 'value' => 1.50, 'bet' => 2],
        ['bookie' => 'NordicBet', 'id_bookie' => 201581, 'value' => 4.30, 'bet' => 'x']
    ],
    'Canbet' => [
        ['bookie' => 'Canbet', 'id_bookie' => 176582, 'value' => 5.60, 'bet' => 1],
        ['bookie' => 'Canbet', 'id_bookie' => 176582, 'value' => 1.56, 'bet' => 2],
        ['bookie' => 'Canbet', 'id_bookie' => 176582, 'value' => 3.80, 'bet' => 'x']
    ],
    'Expekt' => [
        ['bookie' => 'Expekt', 'id_bookie' => 235615, 'value' => 5.60, 'bet' => 1],
        ['bookie' => 'Expekt', 'id_bookie' => 235615, 'value' => 1.50, 'bet' => 2],
        ['bookie' => 'Expekt', 'id_bookie' => 235615, 'value' => 4.25, 'bet' => 'x']
    ],
    'StanJames' => [
        ['bookie' => 'StanJames', 'id_bookie' => 243649, 'value' => 5.50, 'bet' => 1],
        ['bookie' => 'StanJames', 'id_bookie' => 243649, 'value' => 1.53, 'bet' => 2],
        ['bookie' => 'StanJames', 'id_bookie' => 243649, 'value' => 4.00, 'bet' => 'x']
    ],
    'Gamebookers' => [
        ['bookie' => 'Gamebookers', 'id_bookie' => 203620, 'value' => 5.00, 'bet' => 1],
        ['bookie' => 'Gamebookers', 'id_bookie' => 203620, 'value' => 1.50, 'bet' => 2],
        ['bookie' => 'Gamebookers', 'id_bookie' => 203620, 'value' => 4.25, 'bet' => 'x']
    ],
    'Tipp3' => [
        ['bookie' => 'Tipp3', 'id_bookie' => 292604, 'value' => 4.10, 'bet' => 1],
        ['bookie' => 'Tipp3', 'id_bookie' => 292604, 'value' => 1.50, 'bet' => 2],
        ['bookie' => 'Tipp3', 'id_bookie' => 292604, 'value' => 3.40, 'bet' => 'x']
    ]
];
```

This is the unsorted array output, but I want to sort the array where the line is 2, but the line will be changing, sometimes I have to sort where the line is x or 1.

[image]

Comment: @eykanal: I agree with mickmackusa regarding comments on the (now deleted) answer. Questions that are old can (and should) still attract answers and edits. This approach flows from the ethic that we're collectively building Q&A documentation, and such material is always in need of maintenance.

Comment: In relation to answers, the latest approach is that every answer post should be a fulsome response to the question, rather than commentary on the circumstances of the question author, or the pros/cons of the programming language. I appreciate that it is frustrating if an old answer is deleted based on guidelines that were to emerge later, but I think that is how things are run here, for the most part.

Comment: @eykanal Input data should be in a form that is easily ingested by PHP. Valid PHP code (`var_export` output) is preferred over `print_r` output.

Comment: @gre_gor: no objections from me if you want to roll back the edit.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use [`usort`](http://php.net/usort). Here's a small snippet. You can do pretty much want you want in this function.

```
function sorting_function($x, $y)
{
    if ($x['value'] == $y['value'])
        return 0;
    else if ($x['value'] < $y['value'])
        return -1;
    else
        return 1;
}

usort($table_array, 'sorting_function');
```

Comment: This answer does not work on the provided input array. Proof: https://3v4l.org/4MreE

Comment: @mickmackusa It's even worse when you run it against v5.3.6, the latest version at the time this answer was posted.

Comment: Interesting. https://3v4l.org/U6uPM#v5.3.6 I didn't expect that kind of breakage.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the sets and modify the rows by reference.
Call `usort()` to sort the subsets by the `value` column values.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/YL4ei))

```
foreach ($array as &$row) {
    usort($row, fn($a, $b) => $b['value'] <=> $a['value']);
}
var_export($array);
```

Comment: I think they actually want to sort the top array based on the subarray's value chosen by "bet" aka column name.

Comment: Well that has the same result.  Sorting by `bet` to the custom priority of `1`, then `x`, then `2` is the same as sorting by `value`.  Is this what you mean?  The top level keys (and their rows) do not change position at all between the sample input and desired output -- only the subarrays are sorted. I'll agree that the wording in the question isn't awesome.  Shall this page simply be destroyed? @gre

Comment: Look at their image of the table (which is sorted by "1", as is their input data, despite their claim being unsorted). They want it sorted either by the column "1", "x" or "2". You are just sorting the columns themselves, instead of the rows.

Comment: Yes, I did notice that previously.  That very well could be a symptom of the desired result.  I cannot know for sure.